# TSQL while loop vs. merge

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge, while-loop

I'm pretty new to SQL and databases in general. I'm using SQL Server 2008 Mgmt Studio.

I've read that using set-based operations is better than RBAR (just learned that today!).

Shortly I'll show you two equivalent (I think) queries and I'm trying to see which is more 
efficient.

The first attempt:

```
DECLARE @persID int
DECLARE @mag    float
DECLARE @temp TABLE (pID int PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT persID FROM Person

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(pID) FROM @temp) > 0
BEGIN
   SELECT TOP 1 @persID = pID FROM @temp    
   SELECT @mag = SQRT(SUM(value*value)) FROM PersonWord 
      WHERE PersonWord.persID = @persID

   UPDATE Person
   SET magnitude = @mag
      WHERE persID  = @persID
   DELETE @temp WHERE pID = @persID
END
```

The second attempt:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (pID int PRIMARY KEY, mag float)

INSERT INTO @temp
   SELECT persID, SQRT(SUM(value*value)) FROM PersonWord
      GROUP BY persID

MERGE INTO Person AS p
USING @temp AS t
   ON p.persID = t.pID
WHEN MATCHED
THEN UPDATE
   SET magnitude = t.mag
```

These are saved as stored procedures and the Estimated Execution Plan when running:

```
exec FirstAttempt
exec SecondAttempt
```

shows 32% of batch for FirstAttempt and 68% for SecondAttempt

The `PersonWord` table contains roughly 41 million records...the `Person` table contains
roughly 170,000

Any thoughts/advice would be most welcome. Thanks for taking the time, I know how frustrating newb questions can be (used to do math help on Yahoo).

EDIT::

running those on PersonWord having about 1.3 million records and Person having about 3000... the version with merge took ~1.3 seconds to execute. The version with the while loop was 6 minutes in and had only completed ~15% of the job.

For this sort of thing, Set-based not RBAR!

Comment: You've seen the estimated execution plans and can obtain the actual execution plans.  Do you have a question appropriate for StackOverflow?

Comment: In Sql Server Mgt Studio, right click on the query and select `include client statistics`, then run each query a half dozen times or so.  You'll get an extra tab in the output with timing info. "Percent of batch" hasn't been a useful metric for me.

Comment: @HABO yes, for those of you know the ins and outs of sql, is a merge better than a while loop? i've been on here for 2 days trying to find the answer only to get conflicting results

Comment: @DanPichelman thanks Dan, running that now on a greatly reduced dataset (1 mil and 3,000, respectively)

Comment: 1) make sure you have an index on Person.persId - indexes are the number one way to make databases fast; 2) in this case, you don't need "Merge" since you are only doing one thing (an UPDATE would do the same thing); 3) if your @temp table has lots of records, use a #temp table instead of a table variable (temp tables are much faster when there are lots of records) - you can also add an index to a #temp table; 4) good that you are doing the research yourself, but if you find that the set-based approach ends up being slower, then you did something wrong ;)

Comment: @KevinSuchlicki definitely have indexes where they need to be, did change to #temp since the big data set is going to have millions of records, after testing on a smaller data set the set-based approach annihilated the while-loop approach.

Answer (score 3):

Never use a table variable for that number of records.  They are meant for small data sets. Use a temp table instead and index it. Also I would personally look for a way to limit the number of records you are updating. I am not sure why you are using a merge anyway since this is a simple update. The code below should work.

```
Update P
set   SET magnitude = t.mag
from Person AS p
join  #temp AS t
   ON p.persID = t.pID
WHERE magnitude <> t.mag
```

And depending on how you often you are going to do this, I would try to store this calculation so it only needs to happen once for each record (and use a rtigger to keep it updated if the values change):
SQRT(SUM(value*value))

BTW it is a poor practice to float for any math calculations ars you will introduce rounding errors since it is not exact.

Comment: Thanks HLGEM, I changed to using temp table on those.  This and other similar procedures wouldn't get used very often, 4 times a year maybe.  Also, the exact value of mag isn't necessary, rounding even at 10^-6 would not affect the purpose of the mag value.  I used Merge because I read it was basically Update...From, but I like your solution as I more clearly see what is happening.

Comment: MERGE is the TSQL word for "Upsert".  Aka, there is "what to do when you have a match" and "what to do when you don't have a match" (in the source or destination).  If you know you are going to have "matches", use Update (as already suggested).

Comment: @granadaCoder ahh i see, ya when there is no match, nothing happens...went with the update and it works like a dream

Comment: There's no need for a trigger to keep such a field current: just use a calculated column.  Mark it `PERSISTED` if you expect to use the field often and don't mind taking a little more space; leave it dynamic if you expect to use it infrequently and don't mind some CPU cycles when you do.